# Add geometry shader fragment to MShaderInstance

Tags: c++, maya, maya-api

Render items in Maya (`MRenderItem`) get drawn by shaders (`MShaderInstance`), which contain fragments (gpu shader pieces) that are compiled to one big shader just before drawing. `MShaderInstance` allows you to add your own fragments, declaring them first via xml.
My question is, how can I insert a geometry shader into the `MShaderInstance`?
I know they are supported, since the xml schema has an element `geometryShader`, but there are no examples of how to actually define your own.
For example, I have this simple geometry shader, just for testing, that actually does not even generate anything:

```
    layout (points) in;
    layout (points) out;
    layout (max_vertices = 1) out;

    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    }
```

The relevant methods of `MShaderInstance` are `addOutputFragment` and `addInputFragment`. Neither of them works in my case (both return failure code).

I also can't find any examples of this particular case (geom shaders) in the sdk.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Probably this will help you http://around-the-corner.typepad.com/adn/2016/03/create-shader-fragments-as-input-for-stock-shader-and-other-shaders.html

Comment: I'm aware of this, but this is part of the problem. My specific case is about not being able to register a geometry shader.